# I can't get my Python script to import RoboBrowser

Tags: python, robobrowser

So I installed RoboBrowser with the following command:

```
sudo -H pip install robobrowser
```

which then gives me a bunch of "Requirement already satisfied" outputs, probably since I've tried installing it multiple times now.

Then I go to my file's directory and run

```
python myscript.py
```

which gives me the below error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myscript.py", line 8, in <module>
import robobrowser
ImportError: No module named robobrowser
```

Does anyone know why Python won't recognize that I have RoboBrowser installed and how I can go about fixing it?

**Additional Notes**

- When I type in the command `pip list`, I don't see RoboBrowser listed.

Comment: Why are you running `sudo` with the `-H` flag? Try it without the `-H` flag.

Comment: @adeora without the -H I get this warning "The directory  or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag."

Comment: However, I still get the "Requirement already satisfied" outputs and I still get the same error when I try to run the python file